# React Native - Keyboard pushes up content renderer conditionally

Tags: react-native

After adding

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in my manifest file it only solves half of the problem - content that's always on the screen doesnt move, but content rendered after certain conditions are met are still squished. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: use KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: Also tried http://prntscr.com/komyjy  didnt work